# 'Cheapest' way of getting time stamp in Linux (c++)

Tags: c++, linux, timestamp

I am wondering what is the cheapest way of getting a timestamp in Linux (in c++).
I assume it's an accuracy trade-of so I believe there is more than 1 possibility.
I need to have milliseconds but not necessarily `microseconds`, so `std::localtime` isn't an option and `gettimeofday` is probably too costly. (due to the microseconds accuracy).

Comment: Do you mean in the bash / console or in c++?

Comment: We cannot answer until you clarify what do you mean with 'cheapest'. The usual stamping method is to use gettimeofday() and convert the answer to either milliseconds: ((tv_sec * 1000) + (tv_usec / 1000)) or microseconds:  (tv_sec * 1000000 + tv_usec).
EDIT: make sure you use long long to hold the answer on these two.

Comment: @guilleamodeo I added some more info.

Comment: TBH I am not sure why are you so concerned about using gettimeofday() to calculate milliseconds, as no matter what you use you will have to manipulate the value (computer clocks are stored as ticks). gettimeofday() its just a syscall() to the kernel. Actually, afaik gettimeofday() and clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME) use the same code --> http://juliusdavies.ca/posix_clocks/clock_realtime_linux_faq.html.
I use gettimeofday() to the point that in windows, I simulate gettimeofday using GetSystemTimeAsFileTime().

Answer (score 1):

1:  `fprintf(stdout, "%u\n", (unsigned)time(NULL));`

2:    `struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
        tv.tv_sec // seconds
        tv.tv_usec // microseconds`

3: `std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result))
              << result << " seconds since the Epoch\n";`

4:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
milliseconds ms = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
);`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the second isn't cheap at all, the last is the same as proposed on the first answer and contains only seconds, and i'm not sure I understand the first)...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ctime library and the following code:

```
 std::time_t timestamp = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result))
              << result << " seconds since the Epoch\n";
```

This would return in "result" variable the number of seconds since the Epoch (pretty straight forward). There are ways to convert this into a readable format, but that, as you said, is costly. Getting that number would be very efficient because it only reads the variable from the system instead of converting / concatenating and calculating a readable date.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is the cheapest, but I need a better resolution than seconds (milliseconds I guess?)